# .Net 7 ServiceStack 6.4 breaking api route that has just "/api"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, servicestack, .net-7.0

Trying to provide more info and not sure how much is relevant.
One of our webapi is deployed to IIS :  abcdomain.com/xyzweb. We started upgrading our env to .net 7 from .net 5. Web api also uses ServiceStack 6.4.

One of the route defined in the c# Webapi,  ServiceStack plugin is "/api". Until recently requests to endpoint abcdomain.com/xyzweb/api was fine. But now (.net 7 upgrade?) we noticed that the calls to endpoint does not reach the (http get/post method) handler. We have a small middleware defined in startup.cs configure method and see the execution flow through the middleware code when the abcdomain.com/xyzweb/api request is made and the middleware ends by calling next() and after which execution flow lost (webapi is still live).

After much trials, something I read but could not put my fingers on the content, went ahead and changed the route definition to "/apihello" instead of "/api" and then the requests started working as before.

Any pointers what made it break or what made it work?

Searching is difficult with "api", brings only irrelevant results.

I would like to add that before changing /api to /apihello, the http request would return HTTP status 200 (though it did not go to the handler) and Raw response "Error: System.NotImplementedException: The operation '' does not exist for this service".

Comment: Could [this](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/routing-requires-after-host/10733/3) be related?

Comment: Could you please share few more details how have you configured your api endpoint?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron the endpoint is just "/api" for GET,POST and DELETE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me begin by answering that @mythz suggestion according to [JSON /api predefined](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#json-api-pre-defined-route) resolved the issue. But I am hesitant to accept that as an answer.

1. The http request should not respond with HTTP Status 200 when the execution flow did not even reach my request handler.
2. Need to add similar assert [like AssertOperationExists](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/5cea68deed922b4f84fbcbe7dcaa2c1464377621/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Host/Handlers/ServiceStackHandlerBase.cs#L265) that explains operationName is empty and that The pre-defined JSON API route expects a URL in the format /api/{RequestDto} instead of *Error: System.NotImplementedException: The operation '' does not exist for this service* that is of no help.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I've taken the opportunity to use the previous unused `/api/` route to return an index of available APIs ([grouped by tags](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-design#group-services-by-tag)) with links to their direct JSON API Route and to view it in [API Explorer](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-explorer), e.g:

[image]

This change is available from v6.6.1+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

---

You can disable (or change) ServiceStack's [JSON /api pre-defined route](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#json-api-pre-defined-route) with:

```cs
ConfigurePlugin<PredefinedRoutesFeature>(feature => feature.JsonApiRoute = null);
```

Comment: @mythyz The link you referenced is what prompted me to change /api to /apihello. I inferred that the default /api is now treated as a reserved route. But the text was not direct about how this change would break existing implementation and the response from the http request was confusing (I edited my question with the response).

Comment: The pre-defined JSON API route expects a URL in the format `/api/{RequestDto}` - if the Request DTO doesn't match a valid Request DTO name it will fail. Disable the `JsonApiRoute=null` if you want to use `/api*` for other purposes.

Comment: since I see you are contributor to servicestack repo added my suggestions to the answer.

Comment: @padhu FYI an empty `/api/` route now returns a grouped index of APIs with links to their direct APIs and to view the API in API Explorer.